# Array list integer not working

Tags: java, generics, jikes

i am trying to make an ArrayList of type integer, but it gives me this error(I am using this compiler called jikes)
Code:

```
   ArrayList<Integer> = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Error:

***Semantic error: using type arguments to access generic types requires the use of "-source 1.5"'or greater. Compilation will continue to use the raw type "Java.util.arraylist", but no class file will be emitted.

Comment: Every variable needs a name, so give "him" one: `ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();`. And your compiler level is  most likely `1.4`. You need at least `1.5` to use generics. Read the manual/help page of your compiler to find out how to do that.

Comment: Which Java Version do you use?

Comment: Looking a jikes: any good reason you are using just that?

Comment: @Tom: Make that an answer. Because it is.

Answer (score 2):

Your arraylist has no name:

```
ArrayList<Integer> name = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: The reference has no name :).

Answer (score 1):

try following:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Comment: Please can you explain why - code only answers usually require an explanation.

Comment: Because you never named the variable.

Comment: I just noticed that... Whoops. Ignore me.

Comment: @Araymer No problem. You can delete your own comments if you like.

Answer (score 0):

Correct initialization should be

```
ArrayList<Integer> X = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

you need to assign variable

Comment: True, but if i knew what application does i would have given better name.